# Image of morphism between curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I have this projective curve $C\dots y^2z=x(x+2z)(x-z)$ and I have function $f$ on $C$, ie $f\in k(C)$ given by $f(x:y:z)=(y:z)$. What would be image of this function? Can I see it in some way as function between curves? Is image of this function curve in $\mathbb{P}^1$ and which one?

I though that this mean that $x=0$ but that leads to $y^2z=0$, but it only consist of points $(1:0)$ and  $(0:1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in your previous question, the trick is to work in affine charts. This is an idea that will keep coming up over and over $\cdots$ and over again in your study of algebraic geometry. Let us compute the image of the affinization of this curve (an Elliptic curve) in the chart given by $z=1$. Denote this $C_1$.

Here the curve is $y^2=x(x+2)(x-1)$ and your function $f:C_1\to \mathbb A^1$ is given by$f(x,y)=y$. You can see that whatever value $a$ in the image you want, you can get by solving the equation $x(x+2)(x-1)-a^2=0$ which assuming we are in an algebraically closed field, you will always have a solution.

At this point, it only remains for us to check if the point $(1:0)$ is in the image of $f$. And indeed, it is, because if $y=1$ and $z=0$, then the point $(0:1:0)\in C$ satisfies this requirement. So our map $f$ in fact surjects onto $\mathbb P^1$.